# Latex Text in Axis/Title Octave

Tags: matlab, latex, gnuplot, octave, matlab-figure

I'm trying to run some of the Matlab code I have right now in Octave. (I know Octave doesn't support **all** Matlab code) In particular I am trying to run

```
xlabel('Frequency in $\pi$ units','Interpreter','LaTex')
```

However I get an error telling my Octave doesn't support the Latex interpreter. I found a workaround [online](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Re-LaTex-interpreter-td4395346.html) but it is specific to Windows and I am running Linux Mint 14. I was wondering if anyone knew a workaround for Linux, using gnuplot I suppose (or anything else that gets the job done!).

Comment: What happens if you change it to `'latex'`? (rather than `LaTex`)

Comment: Since you asked for "anything else that gets the job done": python with the matplotlib plotting library (http://matplotlib.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer depends on your version of octave.
Set the label as you've done:

```
xlabel('Whatever')
ylabel('Whenever')
```

Then print your answer to a latex file:

```
print -dpslatex 'filename'
```

It is not perfect and the font size cannot be changed, but it is a solution.